# Обособление устойчивого оборота «как за соломинку»

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

1. Вопрос № 200587.  **Нужно выделять оборот с союзом КАК**:  "...*ухватился **как за соломинку** за пенсионеров".*

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Выделение оборота не требуется.

2. В этом предложении не требуется, **а с другими как быть?** Нет ответа. Как можно объяснить выбор знаков следующих примерах?

(1) Эдип, уже чувствующий под ногами пропасть, **как за соломинку** хватается за последнюю деталь, не нашедшую пока себе места: «Почему же ты сказал фиванцам, что царя убила шайка разбойников?»

(2) Гегель опять говорит о «философском бессилии», хватающемся за символ **как за соломинку.**

(3)  Да, дожди, ужасные дожди. Все утро лило, а у вас даже зонтика нет… — закивал смущенный добряк, ухватившись за погоду, **как за соломинку.**

(2) Да он теперь и вообще не искал ничего такого ― никакой абстрактной ясности, за которую можно хвататься, **как за соломинку**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем обособлять? Там же нет сравнения. Люди не хватаются за соломинку в буквальном смысле, чтобы с этим сравнивать. Оборот приобретает значение обстоятельства.

Но есть один нюанс. Чисто грамматически сравнение возможно:
*ухватившись за погоду **так**, как за соломинку;

за которую можно хвататься **так**, как за соломинку*.
А если "так" подразумевается, то запятую можно ставить.

Как выбрать автору? Просто по логическим ударениям, которые ему больше нравятся.

Ещё важно знать, что это правило не является общеизвестным (его не всегда проходят в школах), и кто-то может поставить запятую по общему правилу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сравнение здесь есть, причем в классическом варианте: ухватился за погоду, как за соломинку. Но, как известно, не каждое сравнение обособляется, а может быть необособленным обстоятельством. Но для этого автору надо подобрать подходящую структуру.   В некоторых случаях выбор получается однозначным. Проще всего поставить оборот в начало предложения, тогда его обособлять неудобно. А вот ответ Грамоты сомнителен. Вы можете дополнить предложение так, чтобы было ясным решение  (ухватился как за соломинку за пенсионеров)?

Comment: Ответ Грамоты формальный, без детального анализа. Там оно вклинивается в структуру, особенно на слух. А в таких случаях происходит обособление: *ухватИлся, как за солОминку, за пенсионЕров*. Последнее ударение способствует обособлению. В предложении 3 не вижу значения спасения, единственной возможности — не очень там фразеологизм кстати. *Проще всего поставить оборот в начало предложения, тогда его обособлять неудобно* — а при обычном обороте с "как" в начале выше всего вероятность обособления, а в конце — ниже всего. Например: *Как врач, скажу вам следующее. Скажу вам следующее как врач.*

Comment: Ухватился как за соломинку за пенсионеров.  Повтор в предложении как-то неестественно смотрится.. вам не кажется?

Comment: Кажется........